# Why is correlation between y and $\hat{y}$ in a model with and without intercept equal?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I consider a very simple example with two models like this;

```
set.seed(66)
n   <- 100
x   <- rnorm(n,0,1)
y   <- 10 + 2*x + rnorm(n,0,1)

mod1 <- lm(y ~ x)
mod2 <- lm(y ~ -1 + x)
```

I already checked the following: If I write down $r_{y\hat{y}}$ in Matrix notation with

$P_j = j(j'j)^{-1}j'$ and $P_x = x(x'x)^{-1}x'$ for the model without intercept and $P_X = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ for the model with intercept ill gain $r_{y\hat{y}}$ by

$r_{y\hat{y}} = \frac{ (y'M_j\hat{y})^2 }{y'M_jy\hat{y}M_j\hat{y}}$

Here I just exchange $\hat{y}$ with $P_xy$ for the model without intercept and $P_Xy$ for the model containing the intercept. I already now that stuff like FWL does not apply here. Hence $P_x y \ne P_X y$.

I already checked via simulation and found that the nominator and denominator for $r_{y\hat{y}}$ is different for both models. But apparently the difference is just a proportional amount which cancels out if I do the fraction. What amount is that? I don't get why? What am i missing? I tried already a lot of different approaches. For instance I tried to write $r_{y\hat{y}}$ for the model with intercept as a function of $r_{y\hat{y}}$ from the model without intercept but I could not figure it out quite right...

Comment: One insight is that the correlation coefficient between any two vectors $u$ and $v$ can be computed first by separately regressing $u$ and $v$ onto the constant vector $\mathbf{1}$ and then evaluating the correlation of the residuals, whence it makes no difference whether $\mathbf{1}$ was included or not in the regression of $y$ against $x$.

Comment: Well this is ture but i cant apply this to my problem since im interested in the $\hat{y}$ of each model. If i regress first y on x (or j) and then on j (or x) ill get still different values of $\hat{y}$. This will just equal the partial correlation between y and x (or j). What im actually looking for is a relationship between $P_x y$ and $P_X y$ so that i can express $r_{y\hat{y}}$ for the model without intercept in terms of the $r_{y\hat{y}}$ from the model with intercept.

Comment: i just checked. the amount by which the $\hat{y}$ differ for both models i.e for the one with and the other without intercept do not differ by a constant as one might just conclude by the difference in the parameter estimates. nevertheless the amount in which the fittes values differ is for large x smaller as for smaller values of x. the slope coefficient is in both models positive.

Comment: It just came to me... kinda simple.. Because $Cov(\hat{y},y) = Cov(\hat{a}+\hat{b}x,y) = \hat{b}Cov(x,y)$ we see that the influence of a intercept does not matter. Because in the nominator we have that $Var(y)\times Var(\hat{y}) = Var(y)\times \hat{b}^2Var(x)$ the $\hat{b}^2$ coefficient just cancels out.

Comment: @whuber But the correlation coefficient could change signs for the case without intercept. How is this reflected in the description you gave?